# Is H2O early stop only restrict against ntree?

Tags: pyspark, h2o

I am reading the following two examples

- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/tutorials/gbm/gbmTuning.ipynb
- https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/10/docs-website/h2o-docs/grid-search.html

Both of them when set up grid search, it fix the ntree instead of feed a list of ntree for example

```
[i * 100 for i in range(1, 11)].
```

Here is my question

1. I am wondering is that because early stop is set up against the
   ntree? For example, we can set up ntree = 1000 and
   score_tree_interval = 100, then it can evaluate the model
   performance from 100, 200, ... till 1000. Do I understand correctly?
2. But if my grid search also include learn_rate and max_depth. Will
   the early stop also evaluate against learn_rate and max_depth? I
   mean within the same number of tree for example ntree = 500, when it
   evaluate different learning rate [0.01, 0.015, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1],
   will it stop somewhere in the list of learn rate?
3. In the
   document of "stopping_tolerance" (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/stopping_tolerance.html)
   it describes "the model will stop training after reaching three
   scoring events in a row in which a model’s missclassication value
   does not improve by 1e-3". So what are the three scoring events? are
   they 3 different number of tree or they could be the same number of
   tree but different learning rate?

Comment: Are you asking about early stopping in grid search, or early stopping for building each model?  (They are independent things, and you can specify one, the other, or both; even though the parameter names are the same.)

Comment: Can you help me understand what are the different from early stop for build model vs grid search?

Comment: @DarrenCook That's really a bit confusing. I don't know it until I read you comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Darren Cook mentioned in the comments there is early stopping for each model you build and early stopping for grid search.

For an individual GBM, ntrees (the number of trees) is tuned with early stopping (i.e. using stopping_tolerance, stopping_rounds, stopping_metric specified within the algorithm). You can see this if you open up flow and take a look at the scoring history plot of your individual model. You will see that number of trees is the x-axis.

For Grid Search you have the added layer of your hyper parameters. So if you set ntrees = 100 in your GBM model, and you grid over learning rate = [0.01, 0.015] you will build two models one with ntrees = 100 and learn rate = 0.01, and a second model with ntrees = 100 and learn rate = 0.015. And, for example, in the first model each iteration will have a different number of trees while the learn rate will be fixed.

So looking at your specific questions:

1. yes this is correct
2. the grid will see if there is any improvement between your different learning rates (0.01, 0.015, etc) and max depth. So again what you are saying is correct. The grid will stop if it's not seeing any improvement with different learn rates and max depth values (i.e. it will not continue to build new models).
3. So here you need to separate out the model and the grid search. An individual model will stop building (adding trees) if it doesn't see improvement after three scoring events (and here your learn_rate and max_depth would be fixed while the ntrees would change). Then we step out to the grid, the grid will stop building new models if it doesn't see a user-specified amount of improvement between the individual models it built.

Comment: Lauren, thanks for your explanation. that is very helpful. I have added another 4 questions (4-7) that confused me in my original post regarding early stopping. Can you please help me to understand that as well in your posted answers?

Comment: Hi @Gavin glad the answers helped. For your new questions, I think it would be best if you could create a new post and post it to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h2o?sort=newest&pageSize=15 since these are not really code based questions and are more specific to how the algorithm works.